# Unexpected result from i == j == k?

Tags: chapel

In this code I am looping over all indices in a 3D domain, and printing the "diagonal" part as

```
for (i, j, k) in {0..9, 0..9, 0..9}
{
    if i == j == k              // (1)
    //if (i == j) && (j == k)   // (2) -> gives expected result
    {
        writeln((i, j, k));
    }
}
```

My expected result is something like

```
(0, 0, 0)
(1, 1, 1)
(2, 2, 2)
(3, 3, 3)
(4, 4, 4)
(5, 5, 5)
(6, 6, 6)
(7, 7, 7)
(8, 8, 8)
(9, 9, 9)
```

which is obtained with Line (2) above. But if I use Line (1), it gives an unexpected result like

```
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 0)
(0, 2, 0)
...
(9, 7, 0)
(9, 8, 0)
(9, 9, 1)
```

So I am wondering if I am erroneously using `i == j == k`?
(FYI, the above code is motivated by some Python code like

```
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        for k in range(10):

            if i == j == k:
                print( i, j, k )
```

which gives (0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1), ...)

Comment: Perhaps a comparison like `i == j == k` will be the same as either `(i == j) == k` or `i == (j == k)`? In other words, you compare the *bool result* of one comparison with a non-bool value. Different programming languages do different things. Always read the documentation and learn the language basics, especially when it comes to things like precedence and associativity of operators.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks very much, I think you are right... It looks like i == j == k is interpreted as (i == j) == k (the first comparison is evaluated first, the result of which is converted to 1 or 0, and compared to k). It looks like the behavior is very dependent on languages, so I need to be careful... (I will add a self-answer later.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right on, @Someprogrammerdude.

== is a binary operator, it is left-associative. The documentation is here:

https://chapel-lang.org/docs/language/spec/expressions.html#precedence-and-associativity

When comparing the boolean (i==j) with the integer k (in the context of i==j==k), the boolean is implicitly converted to an integer and an integer equality check is performed.

Comment: Thanks very much! (I tried some more codes, and it seems there are 3 groups of languages, e.g. the "C++-like" group, "make it an error" group, and "python-like group")

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, these are results that I got from other languages (but my usage of each language may be wrong, so please take it as such...).

C++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i = 2, j = 2, k = 2;
    cout << (i == j == k) << endl;
}
// => 0 (false), probably by interpreting it as (i == j) == k
```

Chapel

```
var i, j, k = 2;
writeln( i == j == k );
// => false (same as C++)
```

D

```
import std.stdio;
void main() {
    int i = 2, j = 2, k = 2;
    writeln( i == j == k );
}
// => Error: found == when expecting ) (and some related messages)
```

Rust

```
fn main() {
    let i = 2;
    let j = 2;
    let k = 2;
    println!( "{:?}", i == j == k );
}
// => Error
error: chained comparison operators require parentheses
 --> test.rs:6:25
  |
6 |     println!( "{:?}", i == j == k );
  |                         ^^^^^^^^^

error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> test.rs:6:33
  |
6 |     println!( "{:?}", i == j == k );
  |                                 ^ expected bool, found integer
  |
```

Scala (here ">" is REPL)

```
> var i = 2
> var j = 2
> var k = 2
> i == j == k
         ^
  warning: comparing values of types Boolean and Int
           using `==` will always yield false
  res0: Boolean = false
```

Kotlin

```
> var i = 2
> var j = 2
> var k = 2
> i == j == k
error: operator '==' cannot be applied to 'Boolean' and 'Int'
i == j == k
```

Nim

```
var i = 2
var j = 2
var k = 2
echo( i == j == k )

=> Error: type mismatch: got <bool, int>
but expected one of: 

proc `==`(x, y: bool): bool
  first type mismatch at position: 2
  required type for y: bool
  but expression 'k' is of type: int

expression: i == j == k
```

Python

```
> i = 2
> j = 2
> k = 2
> i == j == k
True
```

Julia

```
> i = 2
> j = 2
> k = 2
> i == j == k
true
```

So, apart from Python and Julia (which are dynamically typed so might be a bit different thing), it seems that more lately developed statically typed languages tend to give a warning (or even an error) against the use of `i == j == k`. So, if Python users may be likely to use Chapel, I guess it might be helpful (for the user) to give some warning (or even an error?) message.

Comment: That's an interesting proposal, thanks @minibean.  It would be trivial to add a `==` overload between mixed ints and bools that generated a warning in Chapel.  It'd be interesting (and also trivial) to check whether it would generate noise for code patterns that we rely on today.

Comment: With a very quick check, it looks as though we could add such warnings without breaking anything important that is part of our repository.

Comment: @Brad Actually, I was surprised that I did not think it "strange" or "dangerous" to use i == j == k when translating some code from Python to Chapel (where the Python code used this double == things). So I imagined that a similar error pattern may appear for someone else (in future), which could be very tricky to debug because the bug is "silent"... So I appreciate it if it could be considered as a potential issue to be treated (in future).

Comment: Completely agree.  If you'd be up for opening an issue on Chapel's GitHub issues page requesting this (either a warning or a re-definition of a == b == c), that would be great and the best way to make sure my experiment doesn't get lost.